# Emptying Parse.com Array field in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have created a Parse.com class in which a field type is Array. I save List with the following code:

```
public void setPreperties(List<String> properties){
        put("properties", properties);
    }
```

The are two senarios:

1. Users will either select one or more properties
2. Or they will select no properties at all.

If the user has selected properties, its saved with the above code.

When the user deselectes all the properties and click save, I pass **null** to the above method to save. But this gives **NullPointerException**.

My question is how can I save empty data in the Array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing an empty list, like `Collections.emptyList()` or `new ArrayList<String>()`.

Comment: Collections.<String>emptyList() worked like a charm. thanks @m-vai